# How to find the shortest path when not all the nodes are connected using A* algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, path-finding, a-star

Im trying to find the shortest path/best path  from Bus Station A to Bus Station B using the A* algorithm where the bus route containing Station A and the bus route containing Station B might not have a common bus station.

(I would also like to change the cost of a move in such way so that i use as little buses as possible to reach my destination)

My BusRoute Class contains a linked list of bus stations,and each station has a name,latitude and longitude

The NODE Class i use to represent the states in A*:

```
public class Node
{
    double gCost;
    double hHeuristic;
    double f;//f=g+h
    Node parent;
    BusStation station;//contains lat,lng name
    String reached;//is either "Bus" or "Walking" , how i reached this node
    int busRouteId;//via which route i reached this station
}
```

`gCost` is the Havesine Distance between 2 stations

`hHeuristic` is the Havesine Distance between the current station and the goal

I keep expanding the node with the lowest f value from the priority queue util it has the goal station

This is the part where i generate all the possible transitions from the current node:

```
ArrayList<Node> posibleMoves=getPosibleMoves(current);
    for(Node p:posibleMoves){
        if(!visitedNodes.contains(p) ) {
            double predictedDistance = calculateHeuristic(p, goal);
            double cost;
            if (p.getReached().equals("Walking")) {
                cost=(10* havesineDistance(current.getLat(), current.getLng(), p.getLat(), p.getLng())) + current.getgCost();
            } else { //Reached using a bus
                cost=havesineDistance(current.getLat(), current.getLng(), p.getLat(), p.getLng()) + current.getgCost();
            }
            p.setgCost(cost);
            p.sethHeuristic(predictedDistance);
            p.setF(cost + predictedDistance);
            p.setParent(current);
            priorityQueue.add(p);
        }
    }
}
```

`getPossibleMoves(current)` finds all the bus routes containing this station and adds the next station from each found route to an arraylist.

After that it adds **"Walking" Nodes** to every other bus route that does not contain this station, trying to connect the routes togheter this way.
(it finds the closest station from each route to the current station)

I set the cost of a Node reached by Walking to be 10 times the cost because a human is about 10 times slower than a bus.

After running the program i am not geting desired results, it either changes too many buses or it seems to walk for no reason.
Also after checking the priority queue sometimes it doesnt poll the node with the lowest f value.

Is this a good way to aproach this problem? Am i missing something?

Comment: It is impossible to say what's wrong without seeing all of your code. But then it will be too broad. Instead of doing `10*` for "Walking" I'd rather added "Walking" and "Bus" edges with the appropriate costs.

Comment: Also I'm really surprized why everyone constantly reinvents the wheel with graphs. Check [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/).

Comment: @lexicore I think [neo4j](https://neo4j.com/) is more popular, but that's only hearsay; I've never actually used either

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.  You're asking for a design review -- what does the computer say about this?  Stack Overflow tends to be for fixing problems in partially-working code.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I've used [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/) extensively and can recommend it from the first-hand experience.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I've never used neo4j but it seems to me that a "graph platform is built around the Neo4j native graph database" would be overengineering for the task.

Comment: Well i messed up the comparator for my priority queue , now it seems to work kinda  chosing the best path and when to walk to change the route only problem is that it uses too many buses i think for each node i will add a variable "nrOfBusRoutesToReach"  and add this variable into the cost? Cost= 80%*nrOfBusRoutesToReach + 20%*actual distance cost ??

Comment: You may want to expand your graph by introducing arrival/departure/transit nodes and connect them accordingly. Then, getting of bus and getting on the next bus will get additional cost of the corresponding edges.

Answer (score -1):

Most beginners in programming underestimate the difficulty of implementing pathplanning algorithm. A* is not a easy-going task, especially if is used with additional constraints. It must defined as a middle-size software project. I would guess that a vanilla A* algorithm needs 500 lines of code, while the extended variant of the OP with priority queue and heuristics needs 1000 lines of code. It is a good practice in software engineering to use UML charts for describing the interactions of the different classes. So my advice is, to download the [dia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dia_(software)) software from the internet, and drawing around 10 classes in the chart for solving the A* algorithm. Programming a pathplanner without any UML chart and in the hope for doing it in one small method is some kind of blind flying.

Two exmple UML chart for pathplanning applications are here: [[1]](https://media.springernature.com/lw785/springer-static/image/chp%3A10.1007%2F978-3-319-26453-0_11/MediaObjects/336829_1_En_11_Fig2_HTML.gif) [[2]](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0098300414000636-gr2.jpg) They can't be used out-of-the box, but they are showing in which direction the project should go. They have around 10-15 boxes connected with edges which are describing a complex software project with lots of classes and methods. Otherwise, the amount of complexity can't be handled.

Comment: The OP asks how to implement A* and your answer is, basically "it's complex, you'll need to draw UML diagramms". I don't think this is a good answer.

Comment: First, A* is not *so* complicated, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) explains it with some 30+ lines of pseudocode. And you don't need to implement the priority queue yourself.

Comment: Next, I really don't see how UML diagrams would help here. You won't have a complex hierarchy of classes or complex interactions between them.